# Verify partial arguments with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I need to set expectation on one single argument. How can I access the received arguments from RSpec?

Here is what I want to achieve.

```
let(:api) { double('API') }

it "should pass :filter in options" do
  api.should_receive(:traverse)
  subject.execute
  args = api.recevied_arguments_for(:traverse) # How to obtain all the arguments?
  args[0].should have_key(:filter)
end
```

To answer the question, fix the line with the comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just figured it out.
Much better than I thought.

```
let(:api) { double('API') }
it "should pass :filter in options" do
  api.should_receive(:traverse).with hash_including(:filter)
  # or with the exact value
  #api.should_receive(:traverse).with hash_including(:filter => 'something')
  subject.execute
end
```

Comment: Note that you generally shouldn't use `should_receive` very much. Your tests should be interested in behavior, not implementation. Therefore, in most cases they shouldn't care what methods are called on other objects, and should just test the final result.

Comment: It's not the case for external APIs. You don't want to execute it HTTP requests. You just want to make sure that the appropriate API has been called.

Comment: Right. But don't use `should_receive` for that. Instead, use WebMock, perhaps with VCR, and verify that the appropriate HTTP requests are getting made. *That's* what you care about, not the method calls within your app. See http://marnen.github.com/webmock-presentation/webmock.html for a quick intro I wrote to WebMock.

Comment: (I neglected to mention that WebMock traps the HTTP requests so that they don't *actually* go out over the wire.)

Comment: No. I don't want to test the API. I'll do it in a separate test (with FakeWeb etc). Here I just want to make sure that the API is being *used* correctly.

Comment: Then you want to test that the proper HTTP requests are being made, I think.

Comment: No. I want to test the API's method is called. I am testing request/response in a separate spec as I said before.

Comment: I think @DmytriiNagirniak wants to test a **client** who makes an API call. So it makes sense to use `should_receive`, but while testing the API class itself, he will use **FakeWeb** and test on http calls.